# Convert numbers to dates

Tags: r

I have a table, one of the columns is dates in form at `20130109` or YearMonthDay with no spacing.

I'm trying to graph these points, and because of this odd spacing, end up with big gaps in the graph, and thus want to convert these numbers into dates.

I've been trying to use `as.Date(as.character(20130107), "%y%m%d")` but that always returns an `NA`.

Comment: Here's a good starter reference for date formatting: http://www.statmethods.net/input/dates.html

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You need `%Y` (4 digit year) not `%y` (2 digit year):

```
> as.Date(as.character(20130107), "%Y%m%d")
[1] "07-01-2013"
```

Answer (score 3):

Using lubridate

```
library(lubridate)

parse_date_time(as.character(20130107), "%Y%m%d")
```

If you wanted to just extract certain elements of the date, this is easy with strftime. For example, just the year:

```
strftime(parse_date_time(as.character(20130107), "%Y%m%d"), "%Y")
```